# What is the best practice to include files in PHP?

Tags: php, include, include-path, dir

I just faced that code

```
include('../wp-load.php');
```

Worked just if script called from web-browser (equals to 'from Apache'). If I'm running the same script from cron or from command line I receiving error

`Warning: include(): Failed opening '../wp-load.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php54/pear') in /home/myfolder/public_html/exe/myscript.php on line 6`

However it worked if I modify the include in the following way:

```
include(__DIR__.'/../wp-load.php');
```

It works from both: command line and from browser.

In the same time I begun to be scared to use includes from the directory where the script placed. So if `tools.php` placed in the same directory is it safe to use:

```
include('tools.php');
```

Or it would be better to add `__DIR__`?

```
include(__DIR__.'/tools.php');
```

Comment: always better include(__DIR__.'/tools.php');

Comment: @PrashantMBhavsar, you meant `include(__DIR__.'/tools.php');` ?

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the script, or in the file that you always include at the beginning, define constant or variable that is the path to your directory root. 
You should define two paths: 
one from your machine, for example:

`define('SERVER_PATH', '/var/www/');`

this will be used for including php script files in your php script

You will just use it like `include(SERVER_PATH.'tools.php')` anywhere in your code. 
You can also use `__DIR__` instead, if you have PHP >= 5.3.0

And second - url path:

`define('URL_PATH', 'http://www.xxxxxx.com/');`

this will be used for things by your page for http requests like images, javascript files, css files etc.

Comment: Is it any better than using of `__DIR__` constant?

Comment: In this case `__DIR__` is better because it always exists, and will also work in subdirectories.

Comment: `__DIR__` is for PHP >= 5.3.0, if it is this version or above, you can use it instead of this SERVER_PATH.

Comment: Could you include this info to your answer? I'd like to accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

Cron has its own working directory, but you can change it with cd:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs
```

You also need to know you can execute multiple commands in cron job like this:

```
command1 && command2
```

So command1 can be the cd and command2 your php.

Then you don't have to add __DIR__ and a cron job will work just like normal PHP.

I know this doesn't really answer your question, but it does solve the problem that made you ask your question. Personally I don't think there's a good reason to always use absolute paths in the includes, relative paths will do just fine in most cases.